# Add border to image on hover with padding

Tags: html, image, css

I just want to add a border for the image with padding also I need transition effect. It's working fine but has a few problems :

> 1. it shows little movements in the image on hover(not fixed)
> 2. Transitions not smooth.

I tried everything.

I applied `box-sizing:border-box;` and gave the image a margin of 2px and removed it on hover but still no luck.

See this [example](http://css-snippets.com/demos/hover-border.html). It's perfectly fine and the image is not moving on hover.

Here is my code :

```css
.home-item1 {
  height: 107px;
  width: 108px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.home-item1 img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.home-item1 img:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-item1">
  <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2s0ftrc.png" alt="">
</div>
```

What am I missing? Please check the fiddle and let me know.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egLw9z8y/5/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you:

I have just added `border: 4px solid transparent;` and removed the `margin` and compensated it with the border and on hover reset it.
**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/hd8tLkac/)**

```css
.home-item1 {
  height: 107px;
  width: 108px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.home-item1 img{
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
  transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.home-item1 img:hover{
 border: 2px solid red;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-item1">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/110/110/" alt="">
</div>
```

Hope this was helpfull.

Comment: i think i gave the same solution :)

Comment: @Zuber Sorry for that I just don't see that early, I have updated my answer in another view. :)

Comment: its okay bro, we are here to help others so not an issue, keep helping, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3):

- First, You need to add `transparent` border to `image` so that it
  will not move when hovered.
- Second, Increase the duration of transition to get smooth effect

```css
.home-item1 {
  height: 107px;
  width: 108px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.home-item1 img{
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2px;
  transition: border 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border: 2px solid transparent; /* Added */
}

.home-item1 img:hover{
border: 2px solid red;
 margin: 0px; padding: 2px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="home-item1">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding a `border` will add to the dimensions of the div which causes the movement.. adding color to a transparent border will not, it achieves the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to boost the transition period and just add border to the image so that the border could be seen for a good time on hover, thus showing a watery like, a bit moving effect to the image. Here it goes :

```css
    .home-item1 {
      height: 105px;
      width: 105px;
      cursor: pointer;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .home-item1 img{
      border-radius: 60%;
      margin: 2px;
      transition: border 0.6s ease-in-out;
      border: 3px solid transparent;
    }
    
    .home-item1 img:hover{
      border: 2px solid red;
      margin: 0px; 
      padding: 2px; 
    }
```

```html
<div class="home-item1">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/" alt="">
    </div>
```